# Disable opencart 1.5.4 product image popup/zoom

Tags: opencart

Greeting,

As per title, does anyone know how can I disable this feature? I have tried below two methods, Neither one works.

**Method 1** in `/catalog/controller/product/product.php` find:

```
$this->data['popup'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($image, $this->config->get('config_image_popup_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_popup_height'));
```

Change to:

```
$this->data['popup'] = 'image/' . $image;
```

in the same file find:

```
'popup' => $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'] , $this->config->get('config_image_popup_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_popup_height')),
```

Change to:

```
'popup' => 'image/' . $result['image'] ,
```

**Method 2** in `catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.tpl` find:

```
<div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $popup; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" class="colorbox" rel="colorbox"> <img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" id="image" /></a></div>
```

Change to:

```
<div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $popup; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" class="colorbox" rel="colorbox"></a><img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" id="image" /> </div>
```

Comment: Method 2.
in catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.tpl

Find:
<div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $popup; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" class="colorbox" rel="colorbox"> <img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" id="image" /></a></div>

Change to:
<div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $popup; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" class="colorbox" rel="colorbox"></a><img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" id="image" /> </div>

Answer (score 2):

After try lots of options, the best and easiest for us has been add those lines in stylesheet.css:

```
.zoomLens {
   display: none !important;
}

.zoomContainer {
   display: none !important;
}
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The right solution should be in `catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.tpl` find

```js
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.colorbox').colorbox({
        overlayClose: true,
        opacity: 0.5,
        rel: "colorbox"
    });
});
//--></script>
```

(should start at line 335) and change it to:

```js
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
/*$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.colorbox').colorbox({
        overlayClose: true,
        opacity: 0.5,
        rel: "colorbox"
    });
});*/
//--></script>
```

Thus simply comment whole colorbox feature initialization...

Comment: @ Shadyyx, thank you. I have tried your method, I commented out below. The popup feature still not disable. <script type="text/javascript"><!--
/*$('.colorbox').colorbox({
 overlayClose: true,
 opacity: 0.5
}); */
//--></script>